# $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ and $\mathbb C$ same first order theory

Tags: logic, field-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

How do you show that $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ (the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$) and $\mathbb C$ have the same first order theory over the signature $(0,1,+,\cdot)$?

Comment: $ACF_0$ is a complete theory. You can find a proof of that fact in any introductory book on model theory.

Comment: I agree with Pece. To show that $ACF_0$ is a complete theory you need to prove quantifier elimination (at least, I would not know any other way). This is well-known but not trivial. It is a theorem credited to (independently)  Tarski and Chevalley.

Comment: Completeness of $ACF_0$ is easy to see by Vaughts Criterion, since two algebraically closed fields are isomorphic if they have the same characteristic and transcendence degree

Comment: $ACF_0$ is the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic 0?